# How to open a number pad on android/chrome with <input type="text">?

Tags: android, html, google-chrome, mobile-safari, android-softkeyboard

Requirement of input is to enter the zip code of United states so it would be 5 integers but it is just a bunch of strings to the application. Markup is HTML5.

- I cannot use `input type="number"` as 01234 would get converted to 1234, bummer for a zip code!
- I am currently using `input type="tel"` to get the number pad to open but I was thinking that a zip code is actually a text and thus I should be using `input type="text"` with some other filter to force the number pad to open, which is what I did, I tried using `pattern="[0-9]*"` but that seems to work only on safari browser (apple devices) & opens the number pad, but opens the text pad instead of number pad on android devices(chrome browser).

So `input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*"` works on iPhone iPad safari browsers but does *not* work on chrome browsers in android devices.

Anyone knows how to get a number pad to open using `input type="text"` on android devices using chrome browsers? Or '`input type="tel"`' is the only way to open a number pad universally on all devices?

Similar question asked sometime back [Phone: numeric keyboard for text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178556/iphone-numeric-keyboard-for-text-input)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437529/html5-input-type-number-removes-leading-zero

Answer (score 3):

A little late to the party I know but...

Using `pattern="\d*"` should work...

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d*">`
```

Answer (score 0):

Input 'tel' was created to enter this type of data and to be cross-device. Using it is smart to input numbers, even though it's text. You're over-thinking this.