# Update input (type="Number") with two digits

Tags: javascript, html

I'm attempting to use Pure Javascript (no jquery if possible).
I need to update my input boxes' value so that it looks like this: `01`. My usecase is for a MM and DD input boxes (mainly for aesthetics). When using the input wheel it will increase with `1`, `2`... I would like it to increment like this: `01`, `02`...

Comment: Can you provide the code that you've tried for us to look at?

Comment: Doesn't seem to be a great user experience as you click the wheel, but throwing something on the `change` event of the textbox to change the textbox value seems to work.

Comment: input type of number can not have a leading zero. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8437529/html5-input-type-number-removes-leading-zero

Comment: Currently I don't have any code - my previous attempt was to just prepend a `0`. I know it's not suppose to but after thinking about it I could parse the `0` out of it then update it manually... but that's just a huge pain

Comment: @hhsnopek here you go, the general idea is there : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7790561/how-can-i-make-the-html5-number-field-display-trailing-zeroes

Comment: It's very simple. If the number is less than 10, prepend a zero.

Comment: @enhzflep its simple in some ways, if that was what <input type='number'> took, however, most browsers format the input type of number to remove the 0, so you'll have to do some fancy changing of the input type as he eventually did

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Daemedeor for leading me to this:

This will change the type to `text` and prepend the `0` on blur. On focus it will change type `text` back to type `number` and remove the leading `0`. All you must do is style the inputs so they don't change widths.

```
    (function() {
      var monthInput = document.getElementById('month');
      var dayInput = document.getElementById('day');

      var prependZero = function() {
        if (this.value === '') return;

        event.target.setAttribute('type', 'text');
        if (this.value.indexOf('0') === -1  && this.value.length !== 2) this.value = '0' + this.value;
      };

      var removeZero = function() {
          this.value = this.value.split('0')[1];
          this.setAttribute('type', 'number');
      };

      dayInput.addEventListener('blur', prependZero, false);
      dayInput.addEventListener('focus', removeZero, false);
      monthInput.addEventListener('blur', prependZero, false);
      monthInput.addEventListener('focus', removeZero, false);
    })();
```

Comment: careful though, looking at the function, it seems that you might want to check the length, make sure its not like 10/11/12 or any number with a length of 2 or greater because that might also be undesirable

Comment: Yeah, I ran into that problem locally and fixed it but didn't update it here. I've updated it now, thanks for the reminder :)

Comment: I realize you are only asking for month and date, but if your input doesn't have a max and min attribute, don't forget to also make sure the length is not greater than 2 instead of just two ~ in case users go past the 30 days

Comment: In that case I added listeners to just notify that the inputs were invalid, with UI/UX