# Angular 9 - Validators.pattern('^[0-9][0-9][0-9]$') doesn't match with leading 0 number like 012

Tags: regex, angular, validation

in order to validate a simple PIN, which can include leading 0, I wrote the following very-simple regexp:

```
^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]$
```

This one works as expected on the different online regexp tools I tried, however, it doesn't work in Angular validator, because of the leading 0 which is not counted as a digit:

```
  PIN = new FormControl('', [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.minLength(6),
    Validators.maxLength(6),
    Validators.pattern('^([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])$'),
  ]);

  formPINGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
    PIN: this.PIN,
  });
```

I can't figure this out despite the different forums I browsed, people are always looking for the opposite.

If an Angular expert sees this post, his help is welcomed!

In the meantime, take care!

**EDIT:**

I have created a Stackblitz if you wanna try something:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzsjn1

here three results:

- the first is not OK because of the leading 0
- second is ok because I added number 6, at the end
- the last one is wrong, obviously.

[image]

Comment: I can't recreate your problem from your code. Can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: You could rewrite that like `^[0-9]{6}$`

Comment: Your regex only matches a 6 digit number.

Comment: @ariel It could be, but that doesn't get to the root of what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks guys for your help, I have updated my main question and I will try to create a Stackblitz if that can help.

Comment: @Sébastien It would definitely help. There is no reason why this shouldn't be working

Comment: @Sébastien could you give me a mock pin to test my solution, please?

Comment: Sure, here the Stackblitz  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zzsjn1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is an HTML5 input element. Try changing type="number" to type="tel" in hello-component.ts (from your link). With it you can technically still enter some non-numeric characters but only your pattern of 6 digits (with or without leading zeroes) will validate. See also
[this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8437640/12769288)

Comment: Thank you Zwiers, you put me on the good way with that post. My solution in the end, is the following:

Comment: type="tel" pattern="[0-9]{6}" maxlength="6"