# PHP MySQL PDO: how to preserve leading zeros of zerofill int columns

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I've hit one more bump in the road of migrating from the old `mysql_*()` functions to the new PDO class:
I have a the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `Id` tinyint(4) unsigned zerofill NOT NULL,
  `UserName` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `TestDecimal` decimal(6,0) unsigned zerofill DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Note the zerofill'ed `Id` and `TestDecimal` fields.

If I run the following code, using the old `mysql_*()` functions:

```
$SqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM test";
$Sql_Result = mysql_query($SqlQuery);
var_dump(mysql_fetch_array($Sql_Result));
```

I get the following output, with the **correctly zerofilled `Id` column**:

```
array (size=6)
  0 => string '0001' (length=4)
  'Id' => string '0001' (length=4)
  1 => string 'alex' (length=4)
  'UserName' => string 'alex' (length=4)
  2 => string '000002' (length=6)
  'TestDecimal' => string '000002' (length=6)
```

However, if I do the same using PDO, like so:

```
$SqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM test";
$SqlResult = $MysqlPDO->prepare($SqlQuery);
$SqlResult->execute();
var_dump($SqlResult->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH));
```

I get this output, with the **incorrectly non-zerofilled `Id` column**:

```
array (size=6)
  'Id' => int 1
  0 => int 1
  'UserName' => string 'alex' (length=4)
  1 => string 'alex' (length=4)
  'TestDecimal' => string '000002' (length=6)
  2 => string '000002' (length=6)
```

It seems like the PDO class is looking at the column type and returning a matching variable type (integer in this case) in PHP.
After some searching I found out about the `PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES` attribute which can be set to force all MYSQL results to be return as strings, while this seems to work (I get a string instead of an int), it still doesn't return the leading zeros:

```
array (size=6)
  'Id' => string '1' (length=1)
  0 => string '1' (length=1)
  'UserName' => string 'alex' (length=4)
  1 => string 'alex' (length=4)
  'TestDecimal' => string '000002' (length=6)
  2 => string '000002' (length=6)
```

It seems to work correctly with the `decimal(6,0) zerofill` field, but not with the `tinyint(4) zerofill` field...
Is there any way to make this work, or will I have to go over my codebase and find out what breaks with this change (I already identified a couple of things which don't work anymore...)?

[Demo code](http://pastebin.com/S8BqTu3j).

Comment: This guy solved it changing to decimal http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6825106/php-mysql-zerofill-is-lost-when-using-mysqli-prepare

Comment: Probably not relevant, but it itches me: what is the value of `$ResultType` (in `fetch($ResultType)`)?

Comment: Works for me. It's possible version issue.

Comment: @RandomSeed: `$ResultType = PDO::FETCH_BOTH;`, I copy/pasted the code from a custom function I created and forgot to edit this out, thanks for noticing, I don't think it makes any difference though... I'll modify the question

Comment: @sectus: I had the issue with PHP 5.4.26 and tried upgrading to 5.5.15, no change...

Comment: @Alex , mysql version? client API version?

Comment: `create table` query?

Comment: @sectus: Updated my question with create table query, also added decimal(6,0) field which seems to work correctly, but I don't know what impact making that change would have (I have a lot of tables with a lot of *int zerofill fields!). Using MySQL 5.6.16 now, will try updating to 5.6.19

Comment: @sectus: Updating to MySQL 5.6.19 doesn't help either...

Comment: @sectus: nevermind, it's not working, I was looking at the wrong output... Sorry!

Comment: Padding zeroes are a visual effect only and should not appear in any business model or business logic. (Numbers should not be compared in any way to their string length. A binary number with string length of 10 might be actually smaller than a decimal with length of 3.) As for a computer `0001` and `1` equals in type **and** content (`===`).

Comment: @sectus: Sorry for the confusion, I updated to MySQL 5.6.19, and first thought this fixed it, however I found out I was looking at the wrong out put then. So I still have the problem, as described in my question.

Comment: Can you provide the shortest code necessary to reproduce problem? Create table, data, whole php script.

Comment: @sectus: Certainly: http://pastebin.com/S8BqTu3j

Comment: @Alex , just checked your code. Works for me.

Comment: @sectus: Are you saying you have the `Id` field zerofilled in both outputs?

Comment: @sectus: OK so why do I have different output than you? Perhaps PHP or MySQL configuration? Could you post your `php.ini` and `my.cnf` files? Thanks!

Comment: i tried to clone your problem on my webserver. with the same table i also get the zerofilled outpout of `id`. only difference i have found so far in my code: `var_dump($SqlResult->fetchAll());`

Comment: my versions: `MySQL 5.1.73`, `PHP  5.3.3-7+squeeze19`

Comment: Does this code works: `var_dump((new mysqli('localhost', $db_username, $db_password, $db_name))->query($SqlQuery)->fetch_all());` ?

Comment: @Alex I've updated my answer please check if it helps

Answer (score 7):

you may use `LPAD`?

try this: `SELECT *, LPAD( Id, 3, '0') AS zero_Fill_Id FROM test`

should change `3` according to int size: maybe 4 for this situation?

**Update:**

I don't think change int to decimal to be good practice, why I'll not go deeper at this, you can search on that subject.

I think you use `mysqlnd` driver, what I've found about it (check if enabled [How to know if MySQLnd is the active driver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475701/how-to-know-if-mysqlnd-is-the-active-driver)):

> **Advantages of using mysqlnd for PDO**
>
> mysqlnd returns native data types when
>   using Server-side Prepared Statements,
>   for example an INT column is returned
>   as an integer variable not as a
>   string. That means fewer data
>   conversions internally.

source: [How to get numeric types from MySQL using PDO?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1197005/how-to-get-numeric-types-from-mysql-using-pdo)

In this case there is `PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES` which in your case should be set to `true`, also you can give try to `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` attribute farther see: [PDO MySQL: Use PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113562/pdo-mysql-use-pdoattr-emulate-prepares-or-not)

```
...
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES, true);
```

Hope this helps in any case or anyone :))

Comment: While this fixed the concrete example in my question, it would require me to over all my code and fix queries everywhere. If I have to do that I'd rather modify the code to work with the real integer values returned from MySQL. Thanks for answering though!

Comment: Personally, I think LPAD's the way to go - but I don't really understand the point of zerofill

Comment: @Alex You would only need to modify the database handle, not each query so I would expect the stringify fetches option to be the easiest  one as you simply set the attribute when you are creating the $MysqlPDO database handler. You will probably also want to change error handling which is a common use case for setAttribute. http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php

Comment: @edmondscommerce: Sorry for taking so long to respond, however in my question I already pointed out that even when setting `PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES` to `TRUE`, it is returning strings (instead of integers), but these strings are still not zerofilled, so my problem remains.

Comment: OK looks like you might have simply hit an issue with PDO that you are going to have to work around.

Answer (score 2):

I'd write small routine to *patch* the PDO output to suit the requirements, and try to make the least amout of changes to the coding.

`$results = pdoFix($SqlResult->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_BOTH))`

```
function pdoFix($results) {
    foreach ($results as &$row) { // note the "&"
      $row[0] = sprintf("%'04s",$row[0]); // zerofill '0'
      $row['id'] = sprintf("%'04s",$row['id']); // zerofill 'id'
    }
    unset($row); // break the reference with the last element
    return $results;
}
```

Note: The other answers are just as good, pick one that you are most comfortable with.