# lastInsertId removes leading zeroes

Tags: php, mysql

This query returns 19 as lastInsertId() instead of 000000019. Why?

```
try {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO TABLE(NAME) VALUES
        (:name)");
        $query_params = array( 
            ':name' => $name
        ); 
    $stmt->execute($query_params);
    echo $conn->lastInsertId();
    $response["success"] = 1;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    $response["success"] = 0;
    }
```

It's not a problem because when I insert into another table with the id of 19 it is inserted as 000000019. I just want to know where do the leading zeroes disappear. Haven't found anything about this on Google.

Comment: That depends on your driver and table definition. Generally speaking, integers don't have leading zeros unless formatted this way to a string (text).

Comment: maybe there is a zero fill on the column?

Comment: Of course, the ID column is UNSIGNED ZEROFILL

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP MySQL PDO: how to preserve leading zeros of zerofill int columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010145/php-mysql-pdo-how-to-preserve-leading-zeros-of-zerofill-int-columns)

Answer (score 0):

That's because `000000019` is a string and it's being cast into an integer by the `lastInsertId()` method.   This will remove all the preceding 0's.

Are you using a layer on top of the native mysqli/PDO objects as that may be doing the casting, we can check the source code to see if that's the case.

Comment: lastInsertId() by itself does no casting and returns a string according to the docs: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php